# Не отображается линия (разделитель) между двух кнопок

Tags: android, android-layout

Нужно сделать разделитель между кнопок, не понимаю как 
Кнопки сливаются в одним фоном, линия, что видна на макете, на устройстве не отображается.

Код layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/startActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.it.irent.irentit.MapsActivity"

    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.66"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="#044d68"
            android:onClick="onClickRegister"

            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#044d68"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:onClick="onClickLogin"
            />

</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Вот как выглядит на самом деле]
[image: По длине он должен быть такой же]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас ширина линии 0

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Если добавляю 1 dp, то появляется просто пустое пространство между кнопками, прикрепляю фото

Comment: Ну... Видимо дело в том, что вы не указали цвет для линии. Укажите его через `android:background`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Настроил цвет, приходится в dp указывать точное положение линии, для своего разрешения настроил, на на другом разрешении, линия будет в другом месте. Да и просвет тоже остается сверху и снизу, его не должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#044d68"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#576ad1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#044d68"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

Установите фон и для контейнера для кнопок. Плюс он у вас во весь экран высотой - так не надо. Настройте высоту на wrap_content и уберите чудовищно большие маргины у линии

Comment: Выставил высоту wrap_content, но ничего не изменилось, контейнер остается на весь экран, если поставить ему фон, он заливает фрагмент